# Empty dSYM folder in Xcode archive

Tags: ios, xcode, crash-reports

I've Googled this extensively, and either the situation someone's experiencing involves a different Xcode version (and therefore different build options), or a presence of a dSYM file.

So, here's the situation. I received a crash report through Xcode. It's just memory addresses. Trying to open it in project gives me the same memory addresses. Thought about manual symbolication but for that I need my dSYM file corresponding to the archive I built. But when I 'Show package contents' for the archive I built in finder, its dSYM folder is empty.

My Xcode settings at the time of archiving were:

`DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT: DWARF with dSYM File`

`STRIP_INSTALLED_PRODUCT: Yes` Switching to `No` makes no difference.

`DEPLOYMENT_POSTPROCESSING: No` Switching to `Yes` makes no difference.

Also, I selected 'Include symbols' when uploading the archive to iTunes Connect.

The process for deployment with Apple is confusing-as-hell enough, without having to worry that when a crash does happen, the resport is in fact readable!

So my questions are:

1) Why was my archive missing a dSYM file?

2) If the dSYM file would've been generated, where could it be?

3) If I really do not have a dSYM file, can I still somehow get human-readable symbol names? I've got the original archive I uploaded and access to source code for that build.

3a) If I Product>Archive again (and assuming this time a dSYM does get generated), can I use this dSYM file instead? Or will it have a different UUID, causing it to be incompatible with the crash log cause...well...Apple?

Xcode version: 6.4

Here's what my crash log looks like in Xcode Organizer:
[image]

Thanks.

EDIT:

I upgraded to Xcode 7.3 before trying this but it may also work for version 6.

The solution to question (1) is to set the following in project build settings:

`GCC_GENERATE_DEBUGGING_SYMBOLS`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For question 1), I also don't know. It may be a bug of Xcode. You can archive
the same code again, then generate a same dSYM file.

For question 2), you can search 'dSYM' in the folder '~/Library', because 'dSYM' file output in there generally. If not found, try searching it in the entire disk.

For question 3), you must have the system library symbol file that the crash log listed in 'Binary Images' section. You can find it in '~/Library/Developer/Xcode/iOS DeviceSupport'. If not found, you can connect an iPhone with the same OS version showed in the crash log to Xcode. After Xcode finished processing it, the system library symbol file of the iPhone can be copied to the folder. Then, you can re-symbolicate the crash log.

For question 3a), For the same app code, different Archive may be have a different dSYM file(UUID). If you use it to symbolicate the crash log, the symbolicated crash line is very close to the real crash line, so this can also help you to infer the real cause of crash.

From your screenshot, there only one line from your app code not be symbolicated. Now, you can generate the dSYM file of your app through using the app code which causes the crash to archive again. After you generate the dSYM file, use command line `dwarfdump -u yourApp.app.dSYM` to get UUID of it,Then check the uuid if contained in  the first line of 'Binary images''. If NO, you can modify the UUID in the first line of 'Binary images'' to same as the new UUID which got from `dwarfdump -u XXX.dSYM`, Note the cpu architecture. Finish this, you can re-symbolicate the crash log in Xcode, or use command line `symbolicatecrash crashreport.crash yourApp.app.dSYM`. Note, you must guarantee the version of your app code same as version in the crash log, if not, the result is unbelievable.

Comment: Regarding your solution to (3), what do you mean by 'Binary Images' section? Where is this section? I've edited my question with a screenshot of my crash log. I don't see any such section.

Comment: The crash log not be shown completely in Xcode crashes. The standard crash log  be explained in [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html#top). If you want to symbolicate a crash log completely, you mush have all symbol file listed in 'Binary Images' section, and every file be marked with a UUID listed in 'Binary Images' section.  Now,  you can symbolicate your crash completely if you have generated  the dSYM file of you code.

Comment: I did 'Show package contents' on the xccrashpoint file, and navigated through to find 3 .crash files. When I open these in a text editor, under 'Binary images', there's just a very long list of .dylib filenames and filenames starting with /System/Library/. What am I supposed to do about these? Do I have to generate a dSYM file as part of this process? Could you please elaborate more. Maybe giving step-by-step instructions? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for editing your answer. I'll try the steps you've suggested for (3) once I manage to generate a dSYM file. Xcode simply doesn't seem to be generating it regardless of build settings. So basically, need an answer for (1) first.

Comment: Hooray. Got it symbolicated, using your steps. I've edited my question to show a solution for (1). The symbolicated file does not really help however, since the only line corresponding to my app (the rest are system library methods), reads `0x000bc2ca std::__1::basic_stringstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_stringstream() (iosfwd:126)`. Not very helpful. Wonder if it's to do with fudging the UUID in the crash log or just Apple's stack trace being <sarcasm>very helpful</sarcasm>.

Answer (score 2):

On XCode 8.3.2, select **Yes** on **Generate Debug Symbols** [image]